# Why does jquery give me a "selector is undefined" error for this code?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I am really struggling with an issue that I hope someone here will take some time to help me with. I'm trying to find the last text selection for a child node named "Emotion" in an xml document using jQuery 1.6.2 and JQM 1.0rc3. The XML document I'm working with has the following structure.

```
<StatusModel>
 <Uid>5e4dc88f-f703-4e34-92f6-609216de6c6f</Uid>
 <Created>Wednesday, November 02, 2011 2:20 PM</Created>
 <User>larry_irons</User>
 <Level>2</Level>
 <Doing>typing</Doing>
 <Thinking>the pain in my neck</Thinking>
 <Emotion>Pain</Emotion>
</StatusModel>
```

The following ajax code retrieves the entire xml document and I see the succesful Get in firebug's console. However, I also receive a "selector is undefined" error message and the function fails to retrieve the text for Emotion as the "var tracking" declaration attempts to do. The ajax is as follows:

```
$('#feeling').live('pageinit', function (event) {


    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/api/list",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (xml) {

            manipulateType(xml);
        }


    });

    function manipulateType(xml) {

        //empty the emotion_type div
        $("#emotion_type").html("");

        //retrieve current emotion to track and append to div emotion_type
        $(xml).find('StatusModel').each(function () {

            var tracking = $(this).find("Emotion").text();


            //append content and tracking variable to div emotion_type
            $('#emotion_type').append("On a scale of 1 (low) to 10 (high) I'm feeling this much&nbsp;" + tracking + ':');

            //refresh the review data div #summarylist
            $('#emotion_type').live("refresh");

        });
    }
});
```

I'm assuming the error message is resulting from the "var tracking" declaration. However, another page in my application runs virtually the same code without an error message. I need two points of advice if someone is willing to engage me on this problem.

Can you see any obvious problem with how I'm declaring the selector?

Can you offer some insight into how I can modify it so that it returns the text of the last child node for "Emotion" in the xml document?

**Update:** I changed to jquery.mobile-1.0.js and jquery-1.6.4.js. The error still occurs.

Comment: [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/), you're doing it wrong..

Comment: Tell me how. According to the doucmentation it is done as follows:  "Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs. We recommend binding to this event instead of DOM ready() because this will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the content is pulled into another page as part of the Ajax navigation system."
 
    $( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
     alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
     });  http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However `$('#emotion_type').live("refresh");` is not, `.live` requires at least 2 arguments (or a map of those arguments)... the event name and the function to call when that event happens. In the documentation, `[ parameterName]` is used when a parameter is optional.

Comment: It's likely that the incorrect use of `.live` is causing the error in jQuery when it does `liveConvert`

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative based on the example?

Comment: It depends on what your original intent was with `$('#emotion_type').live("refresh")`

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the data as a string? In that case you need to put it through the browsers window.DOMParser (firefox, chrome) or ActiveXObject (IE). I doubt it is the actual selector, that looks fine.

Also, it is good to save your reference to $("#emotion_type") before you iterate (and choose a better name :).

```
function manipulateType(xml) {
    var emo = $("#emotion_type");

    //empty the emotion_type div
    $(emo).html("");

    //retrieve current emotion to track and append to div emotion_type
    $(xml).find('StatusModel').each(function () {

        var tracking = $(this).find("Emotion").text();


        //append content and tracking variable to div emotion_type
        $(emo).append("On a scale of 1 (low)...");

        //refresh the review data div #summarylist
        $(emo).live("refresh");

    });
}
```

Comment: raeb, thanks for engaging my question. The xml is retrieved as a document object, not a string. I took your advice on renaming the div from #emotion_type to #emotion_track, and followed your point about declaring it as a variable. Neither of these changes worked. The function is failing at the following point in the .js file -- function liveConvert( type, selector ) {
return (type && type !== "*" ? type + "." : "") + selector.replace(rperiod, "`").replace(rspaces, "&");
}

Comment: Hmm... is there any chance you're doing the GET request before the document is ready?

Comment: Not sure how to tell that exactly but the DOM window in Firebug shows the readyState as "complete" when I refresh the Index.html page. Changed it from "$('#feeling').live('pageinit', function (event) {" to "$(document).ready(function() {" and I still get the same error.